# Error trying to compile kernel 5.15

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, make

I am trying to compile the linux `kernel 5.15.64` but it fails. I have the config and use `make -j4 && sudo make modules_install -j4` but this is the error I get.

```
make[1]: *** [kernel/Makefile:160: kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:1896: kernel] Error 2
```

What is going wrong in the process?

Comment: This is just the very end of the output: Chances are there's some error information above, which you just cut off. But a classical problem would be a full disk at this point.

Comment: There is a bug report https://bugs.gentoo.org/701678 that suggests this can be caused by having `CONFIG_IKHEADERS=m` in your configuration and not having cpio available. Maybe this is your case?

Comment: @icarus That actually fixed it. Thank you! Got into another issue of system trusted keys, but that got fixed from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11).

Comment: The kernel obtained from where? Is this a vanilla or patched kernel? Using what compiler? Is this a cross-compile? User what arch? Under what OS? An amazingly hollow question. Voting to close. This is not how you ask questions.

Comment: Converted comment to answer so you can accept it.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that other users facing a similar problem may find it more easily. For that purpose, please also include more information on where (and in which version) you obtained the kernel souce, as suggested by Artem, and a more complete extract of the error messages, as suggested by Marcus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report https://bugs.gentoo.org/701678 that has the same messages. This was caused by having `CONFIG_IKHEADERS=m` in your configuration and not having cpio available.